# Custom constructors for classes

Tags: c#, class, constructor

I saw this code:

```
this.CreateGraphics().DrawRectangle( Pens.Black, new Rectangle( 0, 0, 200, 100 ) );
```

`CreateGraphics()` is a method, but it acts like a class with static voids. How can I create this in my code? I don't know how this technique can be called...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called *Factory Method* (it's one of design patterns). Basically you create a method which will return new instances of class e.g.:

```
public class Graphics 
{
    public static Graphics CreateGraphics()
    {
        return new Graphics();
    }

    // ... other methods etc ...
    public bool OtherMethod()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
// then you can do Graphics.CreateGraphics().OtherMethod();
```

**UPDATE**

You can use this design patter in other places, all you need to do is to create a method which will return new instance of class (`CreateGraphics` method):

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public static Graphics CreateGraphics()
    {
        return new Graphics();
    }

    // ... other methods etc ...
    public void MyOtherMethod()
    {
        this.CreateGraphics().Something();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that is the CreateGraphics he means, as he is calling it on 'this'.

Comment: The syntax for a constructor does not include the type.  It should be `public static CreateGraphics()`.

Comment: How do you know it's constructor? Victor wrote: `CreateGraphics() is a method`

Comment: Excuse me, I didn't help you to understand what I mean. I am not talking just about `this.CreateGraphics()`, I talk about how can I achieve this effect with any other class in my namespace.

Comment: @Victor I have provided instructions in my answer

Comment: Please take a look at both samples, `CreateGraphics()` method is your answser. It returns new instance of class.

Comment: @des I saw but I wanted to explain to others ;) Thanks.

Comment: @des Sure they do.  Constructors return an instance of the class they are declared in.

Comment: @PeterGluck yeah, but in this case you need to use `new` keyword, so it would look like `(new CreateGraphics).MyMethod()`, you wouldn't be able to do `this.CreateGraphics().MyMethod()`

Comment: @des That depends on the context.  If the call is from within the same class then `this.CreateGraphics().MyMethod()` would work.

Comment: Yeah, but in this (your) case `CreateGraphics()` is a method, (which returns new instance), it is not constructor, if you would want to use constructor then you need to use `new` keyword, right? I mean that instead of `this.CreateGraphics()` (factory method) you would need to do something like this `new CreateGraphics()` (constructor)

Answer (score 0):

CreateGraphics() is returning an instance of the Graphics class.

I suspect you are talking about the Control.CreateGraphics() method,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.creategraphics.aspx

Any method that returns an instance of an object like this, can be used in this way.